# Checking if a node in a binary tree has children?

Tags: java, binary-tree

I'm new to binary trees and I was wondering how I go about writing a method to check if a particular node in the tree is a leaf (has no children)

```
public boolean isChild(int item){
    TreeNode cursor = root;
    if (cursor.getLeft() == null && cursor.getRight() == null){
        return true;
    }
}
```

That's what I have so far.

Comment: Please post your code first? How can I know how you implement your tree? In general `currentNode->next` equal `null` or _not_ tells us the current node has child or not.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, if your Binary Tree object has a `RightNode` and `LeftNode` instance variables you should be able to find out if a node is a leaf with the following code:

```
   public static boolean isLeaf(TreeNode tree){
         if(tree.getRight() == null && tree.getLeft() == null){
            return true;
         }
         return false;
    }
```

Also, I didn't quite understand the purpose of the `int item` as a parameter for the method.

Answer (score 0):

```
TreeNode cursor = root;
```

The above line will make your code faulty. Because every time you called `isChild()`, the function will only check whether your `root` has *left-right* child or not.

Your `isChild()` function should take a tree `node` as parameter and check whether this `node` has child or not.

As you need:

> if a particular node in the tree is a leaf

So try something like:

```
// the following function returns true if currnetNode is a leaf, false otherwise
public boolean isLeaf(TreeNode currnetNode){
    //assuming that caller already checked currnetNode is not null
    if (currnetNode.getLeft() == null && currnetNode.getRight() == null){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the integers in your binary tree are unique, you have to find the node that has that integer value first. Therefore write a method findNode(int item) that returns the TreeNode that has the same value as item. The rest of your method is fine, except that you have to return false if that if statement is not true, otherwise you will get a compile error.

```
public boolean isChild(int item){
    TreeNode cursor = findNode(item);
    if (cursor.getLeft() == null && cursor.getRight() == null){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```